# How to determine if these vectors are in the row space of this large matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

A and B are 8 x 9 matrices. (i, j) entry of B is $i * j - 1$.

(i, j) entry of A is 0 if $i + j$ is divisible by 5 and is the (i, j) entry of B for the remaining entries.

I've managed to work out what these matrices look like.
A is...

[Matrix A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtFsX.png)

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 0\\
    1 & 3 & 0 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 0 & 17\\
    2 & 0 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 17 &0 & 23 & 26\\
    0 & 7 & 11 & 15 & 19 & 0 & 27 & 31 & 35\\
    4 & 9 & 14 & 19 & 0 & 29 & 34 & 39 & 44\\
    5  & 11 & 17 & 0 & 29 & 35 & 41 & 47 & 0\\
    6 & 13 & 0 & 27 & 34 & 41 & 48 & 0 & 62\\
    7 & 0 & 23 & 31 & 39 & 47 & 0 & 63 & 71\\
\end{matrix}
$$

B is...
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 17\\
    2 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 17 & 20 & 23 & 26\\
    3 & 7 & 11 & 15 & 19 & 23 & 27 & 31 & 35\\
    4 & 9 & 14 & 19 & 24 & 29 & 34 & 39 & 44\\
    5  & 11 & 17 & 23 & 29 & 35 & 41 & 47 & 53\\
    6 & 13 & 20 & 27 & 34 & 41 & 48 & 55 & 62\\
    7 & 15 & 23 & 31 & 39 & 47 & 55 & 63 & 71\\
\end{matrix}
$$

[Matrix B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXTs5.png)

I'm trying to determine if the vectors $[9, 64, -71, 42, 49, 59, 234, -196, 97]$ and $[21, 11, 32, 23, -115, 141, 41, 92]$ are in the row space of A and if so; to write the vectors as a linear combination of the rows of A.

I'm having trouble doing this due to the sheer size of these matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I would have embedded the pictures. Not enough points, yet. I did type the matrices out and they are quite large to do so.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you found the (reduced) row echelon forms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I read a vector in is in the row space of a matrix if and only if it is in the column space of the transpose of the matrix. The transpose of A will be 9 x 8. I can't augment the second vector with the transpose of A as it's missing an entry, correct?

Comment: I augmented the transpose of A with the first vector and reduced. I could write the first vector as <9, 64, -71, 42, 49, 59, 234, -196, 97> = -1<0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0> + 5<6, 13, 0, 27, 34, 41, 48, 0, 62> -3<7, 0, 23, 31, 39, 47, 0, 63, 71>.

Comment: @Servaes, is this reasoning sound?